# Why do modern OSses (Linux, Windows, Solaris) implement a one - one thread model?

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, solaris

Reading my textbook for my OS class, which is *Operating Systems Concepts, 8th edition*, by Silberschatz, Galvin, and Gagne, I came across something interesting in the chapter on threads.

In introducing thread models, they start with:

**Many to one**

-Stating essentially this does not provide true concurrency

[image]

---

Next they move to:

**One to one**

-Stating this provides true concurrency, but suffers from thread amount restrictions because of overhead with creating too many threads.

[image]

---

Lastly, they move on to the seemingly evident solution:

**Many to many**

Which apparently takes the best of both worlds.

[image]
[image]

---

Yet if you notice in the one-one section, it states *Linux, along with the Windows family of operating systems, implement the one-to-one model.*

And further in the book after the last image...

[image]

**So if many-to-many is the best solution, why do Linux, Windows, and Solaris (and maybe others) implement one-to-one?**

...and apologies if this should go in programmers SE.

Comment: OS doesn't implement either. User-space threads are in user space, OS implements only kernel-space threads so any of these models is possible in them.

Comment: Have you tried implementing a many-to-many thread system?  I'm guessing no.

Comment: @MartinJames Of course not! I'm just taking an OS course! If that comment is supposed to imply that the answer is "because it's difficult", then that would be better as a plainly worded answer describing that it's difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solaris changed models from *MxN* to *1:1* because the complexity of managing threads at two different levels did not produce the expected benefits, the lack of a direct mapping caused issues meeting POSIX threads requirements in areas such as signal handling, and the cost of creating a new kernel thread for each user space thread was not too high.   Sun published a white paper at the time of the switch which provides more details: [Multithreading in the Solaris™ Operating Environment](https://web.archive.org/web/20090327002504/http://www.sun.com/software/whitepapers/solaris9/multithread.pdf).